# CORS origin request error for POST method in Ionic6 + Angular9

Tags: angular, rest, ionic-framework, crud

I am trying to POST using Angular's HttpClient. I am getting an error as below :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://url.com' from origin
>   'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I have also tried with mentioning the headers as below

```
this.httpClient.post(this.url,JSON.stringify(data),{
  headers:{
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS',
  }
}).subscribe(res=>{
  console.log(res);
})
```

I have also ensured that data type is JSON.
GET method calls works fine but post method isn't working as expected even after adding headers.

Comment: The CORS headers ( `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`) needs to be set on your server not your client. Do you have access to the server ?

Comment: Yes I am able to do GET calls.

Answer (score 1):

The CORS headers should be applied on the server side, not on the client side.

According to Wikipedia:

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows
>   restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain
>   outside the domain from which the first resource was served.[1]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

So it should not make any sense if you provide CORS headers in your client.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is largely related to the back-end 
make sure to send the parameters correctly and you can try this extension for chrome
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

or this one for firefox
https://addons.mozilla.org/ar/firefox/addon/access-control-allow-origin/

Comment: I am able to make POST calls fine using Postman. Only when I make PST calls from localhost is that I face this kind of issue.

Comment: yes you can make requests using postman but you cant make request using browser
try those extensions it well work correctly but the real problem in back-end 
tell back-end developer to add  **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header